# How To Post Link To Friends Wall Using The Facebook IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for some advice on the best approach to achieve posting to a users wall from either the IOS App or my server.

**Background**

My app is currently available and incorporates the Facebook SDK. At the minute there is a custom social network in the app where users can join via Facebook Connect and share their edited photos. The user in the app uploads their photos to my server and then the app will fetch them for other users to see i.e. (latest, categories) etc.

I am looking at creating a web based viewing platform, think instagram where the users can also see their photos.

**Goal**

At the point of upload from the app I want to be able to post to the users friends on Facebook with a link to the web based image. I am unsure whether or not to send the notification from the app or post it from the server.

Can someone point out what it is that I need to do to achieve the above? I would imagine that I need to ask for extended permissions and then post an open graph notice. Is this correct?